# Navigating an IVR with Twilio

Tags: ruby, twilio

I am trying to navigate an known IVR, that ends with the last input forwarding to a real person. When that person picks up, I want to make a call back to the app to play an mp3. Using `sendDigits` https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post with call creation works for navigating the menu, but the callback to the `url` parameter happens when the call is answered by the IVR instead of the end user. So in that case, the mp3 is already playing by the time the person the call is forwarded to answers.

The other way I was thinking of trying involved not using `sendDigits` with call creation, but using a different `url` callback to grab TwiML and use `Play` https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play to play the DTMF tones needed. In this scenario though, reading though the docs, I don't see a way to send a callback url that would be called when the call is forwarded and the person picks up.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you want a webhook when your DTMF tones are finished and the call is put through to a human, you could try your second option using [`<Play>` to send DTMF tones](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play#examples-2) and then use a [`<Redirect>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/redirect) to cause a new webhook to occur. Like this:

```
<Response>
  <Play digits="1234"></Play>
  <Redirect>http://example.com/play_mp3</Redirect>
</Response>
```

If you find that you are still playing the mp3 before a person has actually answered, you can use [`<Pause>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/pause) to wait before sending the `<Redirect>`.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks! While that would delay the mp3 from playing until after the DTMF tones are played, you are still guessing when to start playing the mp3. If the time to answer is greater than the time to make the call to that webhook and grab the TwiML to play the mp3, then the same problem would exist, albeit to a lesser extent. Adding `<Pause>`s could help, but then you are still guessing and could end up with the reverse problem.

Comment: The closest thing I can find to what I need is using the  `<Dial>` verb with the `<Number>` noun which accepts a callback url for when the party picks up, as well as `sendDigits`. However, this doesn't work either as `<Number>` expects a valid phone number and doesn't seem to execute the `sendDigits` without a number to dial first.

Comment: So, once you've entered the DTMF tones does the phone ring again until the agent on the other end picks up? And you need to know when that ringing is over?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And given that it is initiated by the the IVR system, I'm unsure if Twilio has the ability to know that another party is being connected to their call.

Comment: Ah, we do not have that ability. From Twilio's end all we are getting is a stream of audio, we don't know what the other IVR is doing.